# Error while trying to add record to access2016 table from excel2016

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using front end as Excel2016 and back end is Access2016. This is a shared file to be used by multiple users for data entry.

When I am trying to add a record it is added fine, but error (Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype) is encountered when another user tries to add a record.

I am opening and closing connection after every read/write in my code so that multiple users can do the data entry.

Following is my current code:

```
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strDBName = "Test Excel Access.accdb"
strDB = strPath & "\" & strDBName

ConnDB.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

strTable = "Table01"

adoRecSet.Open Source:=strTable, ActiveConnection:=ConnDB, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

With adoRecSet
    .AddNew
    .Fields(1) = TextBox1.Text
    .Fields(2) = TextBox2.Text
    .Fields(3) = TextBox3.Text
    .Fields(4) = TextBox4.Text
    .Fields(5) = TextBox5.Text
End With

adoRecSet.Close
Set adoRecSet = Nothing
ConnDB.Close
Set ConnDB = Nothing
```

I have checked multiple forums and questions on the internet but all are related to cursor type or lock type, which I have used correctly as per those solutions.

Additionally, I find it strange that it works fine for me but gives error when other user tries to invoke the same code.

**EDIT1:**

Upon further analysis I think that this is limitation of ms access and multiple users cannot update the table that I have created directly. It could however be possible by use of queries.
I have created an insert query in access, but I am not able to execute it.
`    open_connection

```
cmd.ActiveConnection = ConnDB

Set fn = cmd.CreateParameter("FirstName", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 30, TextBox1.Text)
Set ln = cmd.CreateParameter("LastName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, TextBox2.Text)
Set age = cmd.CreateParameter("Age", adUnsignedTinyInt, adParamInput, , TextBox3.Text)
Set exp = cmd.CreateParameter("Experience", adUnsignedTinyInt, adParamInput, , TextBox4.Text)
Set tech = cmd.CreateParameter("Technology", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextBox5.Text)

cmd.Parameters.Append fn
cmd.Parameters.Append ln
cmd.Parameters.Append age
cmd.Parameters.Append exp
cmd.Parameters.Append tech

strQuery = "InsertQuery"

adoRecSet.Open strQuery, ActiveConnection:=ConnDB, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic`
```

It gives error on open statement stating that it expects "INSERT", "UPDATE" etc. but does not invoke the "InsertQuery" that I am trying to pass as argument.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried doing an INSERT INTO sql sentence instead of using Recordset.AddNew?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns   I have tried that and it failed.. Updated original post with **EDIT1**, please have a look and let me know if you can find reason for the error...

Answer (score 0):

Executing SQL queries from VBA is easy, just need to do something like this...

```
    strSQL = "Insert into table(col1, col2, 
    col3) values (" & Cells(X,X).Value & ", " & Cells(X1,X1) 'etc
    Debug.Print strSQL
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Just be sure to clean all the variables you are adding before the execute

Edit: Replicating this on my end I have no problems at all so I'm not sure how much more help I can be without actually seeing table definitions etc. Only thing I can think of is if the table doesn't have a primary key it might throw some weird errors.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but again it runs fine for me but fails for other users stating query should be updatable.